# Searching for a row with a certain insert value, then comparing a value in that row with an insert value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create an update trigger that checks the quantity of a product in stock over how much someone is ordering and displays a message if not enough of that product is in stock.

It's letting me create the trigger but when testing, it displays an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=,...."

I'm not really understanding how it's returning more than one value as I have it searching for the particular row with the product ID that matches the inserted value first. I then have it comparing the UnitsInStock from the inserted value.

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER  tr_check_qty
ON  OrderDetails
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @ProductID  int,
    @Quantity   int

SELECT  @ProductID = ProductID,
    @Quantity = Quantity
FROM    inserted
WHERE   @ProductID = ( SELECT ProductID FROM Products )

IF 
@Quantity > ( SELECT UnitsInStock FROM Products )
BEGIN
    PRINT   'Not enough product in stock'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Your trigger is broken - you're assuming that `inserted` only contains one row, which is *not* a correct assumption in general. (Triggers run once per *statement*, not once per *row*)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER  tr_check_qty
ON  OrderDetails
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM
       Products p
          inner join
       inserted i
          on p.ProductID = i.ProductID
   WHERE i.Quantity > p.UnitsInStock)
BEGIN
    PRINT   'Not enough product in stock'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

However, I'm a bit mystified on why this is inside an *update* trigger, as compared to an *insert* trigger.

Comment: A silly guess: this is a trigger *for update*, i.e. it is supposed to update you with the information that there's not enough product in stock. :) Seriously though, I think it should be both for update and for insert.

Comment: It's an update because the order already exists... it's just if you want to change the product.  But thanks, that helped :)

Comment: Ah, good point... I guess it probably should be for both.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT UnitsInStock FROM Products` as well as `SELECT ProductID FROM Products` may return a whole column, not a single value. You should specify some restriction there, like `WHERE id = @someId`.

Answer (score 0):

You have more the one products right?

Then this line:

```
WHERE   @ProductID = ( SELECT ProductID FROM Products )
```

And this line:

```
@Quantity > ( SELECT UnitsInStock FROM Products )
```

will return many rows.

Note as well that if you insert more then one row. The `inserted` table will have more then one row as well

You might want have to do something like this:

```
IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            NULL 
        FROM 
            inserted 
        WHERE EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 
                    NULL 
                FROM 
                    Product 
                WHERE 
                    Product.Quantity>inserted.Quantity
            )
    )
BEGIN
    PRINT   'Not enough product in stock'
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```